# Visual Basic DataGridView to PDF Exception Error

Tags: vb.net, pdf, datagridview

Okay I am trying to print a DataGridView to Pdf in Visual Basic.net  I keep getting an NullReferenceException was Unhandled error.  I need some help please.

```
 Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    'Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data

    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(DataGridView1.ColumnCount)

    pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3

    pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30

    pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT

    pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1





    'Adding Header row

    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns

            Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))

            cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240)

            pdfTable.AddCell(cell)

        Next



        'Adding DataRow

        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells

                **pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())** (this is where the exception is thrown)

            Next

        Next



        'Exporting to PDF

        Dim folderPath As String = "C:\Users\mnevi\Documents\testpdf"

    If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then

        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)

    End If

    Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create)

        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)

        pdfDoc.Open()

        pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)

        pdfDoc.Close()

        stream.Close()

    End Using
End Sub
```

I have marked the code that is throwing the exception above with **.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells

                **pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())** (this is where the exception is thrown)

            Next
```

To something more like this:

```
For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
  Dim val = If(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell?.Value?.ToString), cell?.Value?.ToString, String.Empty)
                pdfTable.AddCell(val)

            Next
```

Without knowing more about the PDF writer you are using I can only assume it is blowing up on a common null reference.  With the '?.' operator I am saying if the parent or the child is null equate it the same.  So essentially I am checking for nothing and then if it has something, providing it, else giving a blank which at least is something.

Comment: Well it no longer throws the error when I do that but it also does not create the pdf.  Hmm The NullReferenceException says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. While pointing to the original line of code.  I am using iTextSharp as the pdf writer.

Comment: Set breakpoints and ensure that you objects are getting correctly populated would be my guess.